# Wordpress Change how Navigation Menu Renders

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, navigation

I need to add a P tag surrounding the menu items text, in between the A tags in wordpress.

It currently renders like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need it like this:

```
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Item 1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Item 2</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Item 3</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What file do I edit to do this?

Comment: which menu? navigation, side or what?
edit: it also depends on your theme.

Comment: Sorry, the main navigation menu, the files I've found that look like they may be right to edit are - nav-menu-template.php, and nav-menu.php - in wp-includes

Comment: override defaults values  - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix:

1.) Under Appearance, select Menus.

2.) Change the Navigation Label to be: `<p>LABEL</p>`

Permanent fix:

Depending on your theme this will vary...

1.) head over to Appearance, select editor and scroll down untill you find `Header (header.php)`

2.) find this code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'theme_location' => 'top-menu', 
            'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="top-navigation" class="left">%3$s</ul>',
            'container' => false,
            'fallback_cb' => 'codon_link_to_menu_editor',
            )
            ); 
            ?>
```

and change it to:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'theme_location' => 'top-menu', 
            'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="top-navigation" class="left"><p>%3$s</p></ul>',
            'container' => false,
            'fallback_cb' => 'codon_link_to_menu_editor',
            )
            ); 
            ?>
```

Not sure if this works for you, it worked for me when using the theme "codon"